# Is the app version I download always the latest?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have recently submitted an app to the Android market to quickly realize that I had left in a bit of code that needed to be removed. I quickly re-submitted a new version but was wondering if the market makes you download version 1 and update.

I could not see this being the case but when I tried to re-download the new version after removing the old one from my phone - it was exactly the case. The faulty version 1 was downloaded and I needed to manually update it to v1.1.

If anyone has any ideas or would like to help me out by maybe downloading the app and letting me know which version you were given that would be great - [**App Link**](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.stringerapps.games.tapitfree&feature=search_result).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way this would happen is if you downloaded the old version of your app before Google had "pushed out" the new version you uploaded.  If you download an app you won't get anything but the most recent version Google has available.  I assume you just didn't wait quite long enough after uploading before trying to download it.